# hector mapping map size

Tags: navigation, mapping, hector-mapping

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello everybody!

I am currently mapping a small tunnel, with about 200m in length and I'm using hector slam with a laser scanner.
All working good so far, but with the exception that the map size is not big enough.
I have to set the maps size manually via map_size in the launch file before I really know how big the map will be. This may lead to moving outside the map area and not being able to map any further. Setting up a map_size of 20000 etc. is not an option, since it would use up too much space.

Is there a way to dynamically increase the map size?

Cheers and thanks in advance

Bobby

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/257712/hector-mapping-map-size/) by [bobbyros](https://answers.ros.org/users/29790/bobbyros/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2017-03-23

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Try [rqt_reconfigure](http://wiki.ros.org/rqt_reconfigure). You should then be able to change parameters dynamically.

Cheers,
Goldie

---

Originally posted by [Goldie](https://answers.ros.org/users/31552/goldie/) with karma: 31 on 2017-10-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Sj_Nath](https://answers.ros.org/users/117255/sj_nath/) on 2022-10-12**:
When I am running rqt reconfigure, I am not seeing any option for increasing map size.  kindly help.